# How to recover the outlook emails for a deleted email account

Tags: outlook, account

I accidentally delete my email account and so all of the emails in that account. Is there a chance to recover the emails? How can I recover it? Thanks.

Comment: How did you delete? from account setting?

Comment: Yes, I deleted it from the account setting to have a fresh account.

Comment: Is that recoverable?

Comment: try looking at `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`

Comment: If it is not there, what would be next? Any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four months ago I would have agreed with Om3r's comment giving the location of the Outlook stores. But I bought a new laptop in December and now the Outlook files are not where all the documentation says they should be.  Worse, I cannot reach the folders containing the Outlook files using File Explorer although I can find them with VBA.

The macro below searches drive C for files with an extension of OST or PST.  I cannot promise this macro will find your lost store but, if it is still on your disc, it will find it.  If you find the missing store, you will probably have to use VBA to move it to somewhere accessible.

Copy the macro below to a macro-enabled workbook and run it.  While it is running the active worksheet will look like:

```
1923 Folders to search
 327 Folders searched           

     Store       Size      Date Folder
     $ILJARJ0.pst   212   28Mar20 C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-3957073674-21115239-22921093-1001
     $IMS96DJ.pst   212   28Mar20 C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-3957073674-21115239-22921093-1001
```

The top two rows give a crude progress indicator.  On my laptop, the routine ends with 69190 folders searched.  I do not know why there are PST files in my recycle bin.  I did nothing relevant on 28 March.  When the routine has finished, there will be a auto-fitted list of every store the macro found.  On my laptop none are where I would expect and some are duplicates.  I hope you find your store.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SearchForStoresOnC()

  ' Searches drive C for files with an extension of PST or OST
  ' Warning: overwrites the active workbook

  Dim ErrNum As Long
  Dim FileAttr As Long
  Dim FileName As String
  Dim FldrName As String
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim ToSearch As Collection

  Cells.EntireRow.Delete
  Range("A1").Value = 0
  Range("A2").Value = 0
  Range("B1").Value = "Folders to search"
  Range("B2").Value = "Folders searched"
  Range("B4").Value = "Store"
  With Range("C4")
    .Value = "Size"
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
  End With
  With Range("D4")
    .Value = "Date"
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
  End With
  Range("E4") = "Folder"
  RowCrnt = 5

  Set ToSearch = New Collection
  ' Load ToSearch with drive to search.
  ToSearch.Add "C:"

  Do While ToSearch.Count > 0

    FldrName = ToSearch(1)
    ToSearch.Remove 1

    Err.Clear
    ErrNum = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Stores are unlikely to be hidden but can be in folders that are hidden
    FileName = Dir$(FldrName & "\*.*", vbDirectory + vbHidden + vbSystem)
    ErrNum = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ErrNum <> 0 Then
      'Debug.Print "Dir error: " & FldrName
    Else
      Do While FileName <> ""
        If FileName = "." Or FileName = ".." Then
          ' Ignore pointers
        Else
          Err.Clear
          On Error Resume Next
          FileAttr = GetAttr(FldrName & "\" & FileName)
          ErrNum = Err.Number
          On Error GoTo 0
          If ErrNum = 0 Then
            ' Ignore file and folders which give errors
            If (FileAttr And vbDirectory) = 0 Then
              ' File
              'Debug.Assert False
               Select Case Right$(FileName, 4)
                 Case ".pst", ".ost"
                 Cells(RowCrnt, "B").Value = FileName
                 With Cells(RowCrnt, "C")
                   .Value = FileLen(FldrName & "\" & FileName)
                   .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
                 End With
                 With Cells(RowCrnt, "D")
                   .Value = FileDateTime(FldrName & "\" & FileName)
                   .NumberFormat = "dmmmyy"
                 End With
                 Cells(RowCrnt, "E").Value = FldrName
                 RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
               End Select
            Else
              ' Directory
              ToSearch.Add FldrName & "\" & FileName
            End If  ' File or Directory
          Else
            'Debug.Print "FileAttr error: " & FldrName & "\" & FileName
          End If  ' FileAttr does not give an error
        End If ' Pointer or (File or Directory)
        FileName = Dir$
      Loop  ' For each pointer, file and sub-directory in folder
    End If  ' Dir$ gives error

    Range("A1") = ToSearch.Count
    Range("A2") = Range("A2") + 1
    DoEvents

  Loop  'until ToSearch empty

  Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```